# Mathjax: how to ignore certain commands?

Tags: support, mathjax

I'm writing a document in emac's `org-mode`, which exports both to Latex and to HTML. For the HTML portion, it uses `Mathjax`.

Now, I have some equation that uses the `\textsc{x}` command. This works fine within Latex, but not in Mathjax as it is not supported.

I want to tell Mathjax to simply ignore the `\textsc` commands, and just use whatever is inside "plainly". I.e. `\textsc{x} = x`. Is this possible?

Edit: to clarify: I want to export to both Latex and HTML. I want the `textsc` to be in my Latex pdf, but ignored by Mathjax. Removing all `textsc` therefore is not a solution, as then it will be absent in the Latex pdf as well.

Comment: Questions about MathJax outside of its use on math.stackexchange.com are off-topic here. Stackoverflow has a mathjax tag and MathJax has an [official user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users) for general support.

Comment: @Trevor it's also in LaTeX as easy as \iflatextrue ... \else ...\fi

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Do not type the `\textsc` part into your answer, and if you copy-paste, then remove it.

---

If you want a less-manual hack, go to the start of your text:

`M-x replace-regexp <RET> \\textsc{\([^\}]*\)} <RET> \1 <RET>`

This should do the trick.

Comment: I still want to be able to export to Latex pdf **with** the `textsc` in place. Removing it therefore is not an option. I have updated my question to reflect this situation

Comment: Here's a partial solution for you.

Comment: why not set a if* up so you can turn it true or false for the document ? you want...